# How to Transcode HTTP DELETE with Request Body to gRPC

Tags: http, grpc, http2, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

I'm new in using gRPC with proto3, and I've used `Transcoding HTTP/JSON to gRPC` to migrate existing http endpoints to grpc.

But I have http DELETE request with request body. I have tried following and got an error.

Grpc Endpoint :

```
  rpc DeleteFile(DeleteFileRequest) returns (DeleteFileResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      delete: "/v2/file/delete/{path}"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
```

protoc gererate command as below

```
protoc -I ./proto --go-grpc_out=. --go_out=. --grpc-gateway_out=. --openapiv2_out=./openapi ./proto/myapp.proto
```

Error I have Got

```
--grpc-gateway_out: must not set request body when http method is DELETE except allow_delete_body option is true
```

And then I have add `--allow_delete_body=true` to my protoc command as below.

```
--allow_delete_body=true
error : Unknown flag: --allow_delete_body

--grpc-gateway_opt allow_delete_body=true 
error : must not set request body when http method is DELETE except allow_delete_body option is true
```

grpc versions in my go.mod

```
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2 v2.3.0
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware v1.3.0
google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20210224155714-063164c882e6
google.golang.org/grpc v1.36.0
google.golang.org/protobuf v1.26.0
```

Would anyone kindly explain How I transcode HTTP DELETE to grpc with request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spent time on web and trying with applying flags in different ways, I have found the working command for me. Thanks everyone help to resolve this.

This is the working command for me:

```
protoc -I ./proto --go-grpc_out=. --go_out=. --grpc-gateway_out=allow_delete_body=true:. --openapiv2_opt allow_delete_body=true --openapiv2_out=./openapi ./proto/myapp.proto
```

Comment: there is analog option for get-request?

Answer (score 1):

The protoc always has wired issues. Suggest use [buf](https://buf.build/) instead. And the config of buf.gen.yaml should like this and it works well:

```yaml
version: v1beta1
plugins:
  - name: go
    out: proto
    opt: paths=source_relative
  - name: go-grpc
    out: proto
    opt: paths=source_relative,require_unimplemented_servers=false
  - name: grpc-gateway
    out: proto
    opt:
      - paths=source_relative
      - allow_delete_body=true
```

For this question, I found answer in [Not able to pass allow_delete_body to protoc-gen-grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/402#issuecomment-304744240), this command works for me, but not work after add `--openapiv2_out=./openapi`:

```sh
protoc -I ./proto --go-grpc_out=. --go_out=. --grpc-gateway_out=allow_delete_body=true:. ./proto/myapp.proto
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I can not change protoc at the moment. So I need to find a way to do this with protoc. For the future development, I will keep in mind your suggestion.

Comment: Updated the question with that.

Comment: @nipuna there is analog option for get-request?